# I have a problem when I was installing polyglot using windows

Tags: python, nlp, tex

pip install polyglot

And the result is:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d0s6d5w6\polyglot\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d0s6d5w6\polyglot\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-7h9sjvs8'
cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d0s6d5w6\polyglot
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d0s6d5w6\polyglot\setup.py", line 15, in 
readme = readme_file.read()
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4941: character maps to 
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
pip install polyglot==15.10.03
```